# How do I dynamically add and remove fragment pages using Viewpager2 and Mediator Tab Layout

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tablayout, android-viewpager2

I need to add fragments to viewpager2 as well as tabs at runtime depending on server config file.
Most viewpager2 resources I have seen showcase a static viewpager2 using the new TabMediator Tab layout.
I am skipping viewpager as I need to add RTL and vertical scrolling supported by viewpager2.

My biggest concern is how to I track the index of a specific page/fragment when I add and remove fragments.
Have gone through [this](https://github.com/android/views-widgets-samples/tree/master/ViewPager2) tutorial and code as an exapmple.

Comment: Did you find an answer?

Comment: This helped me resolve my issue - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61406176/viewpager2-not-able-to-dynamically-add-remove-fragment

Comment: Will check that out.

Comment: @artman this is not the proper solution. If I have only one fragment and trying to browse through different tab with different data.

Comment: @cap_muho please let me know if you found any solution.

Comment: @cap_muho do you find any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you implement it in Kotlin

```
viewPager = binding.viewPagerContainer
        val tabLayout : TabLayout = binding.tabLayout

        val fragmentList : MutableList<Pair<String, Fragment>> = mutableListOf()
        fragmentList.add(Pair(getString(R.string.assets), AssetFragment.newInstance()))
        fragmentList.add(Pair(getString(R.string.news), NewsFragment.newInstance()))

        val adapter = AppFragmentAdapter(fragmentList, this)

        Handler(Looper.myLooper()!!).postDelayed({
            adapter.addFragment(Pair(getString(R.string.videos), VideosFragment.newInstance()))
        }, 1000)

        Handler(Looper.myLooper()!!).postDelayed({
            adapter.removeFragment(2)
        }, 2000)

        viewPager.adapter = adapter
        viewPager.offscreenPageLimit = 2

        val layoutInflater : LayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context)

        viewPager.registerOnPageChangeCallback(object : ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback() {

            override fun onPageSelected(position: Int) {
                super.onPageSelected(position)
                val actionBar : ActionBar = (requireActivity() as AppCompatActivity).supportActionBar!!
                actionBar.title = adapter.getFragmentName(position)
            }

        })

        TabLayoutMediator(tabLayout, viewPager){ tab, position ->
            tab.customView = prepareTabView(layoutInflater, tabLayout, adapter.getFragmentName(position), tabIcons[position])
        }.attach()
```

Here we already tested to add and remove the last fragment using some basic delay upon launching an Activity or Parent Fragment. You can create a custom view for each tab or just use tab.text = "Tab Name" for simplicity.

Now the type of adapter you will be using with ViewPager2 for Fragment is `FragmentStateAdapter`

```
class AppFragmentAdapter(private val fragmentList: MutableList<Pair<String, Fragment>>, fragment: Fragment) : FragmentStateAdapter(fragment) {

//    private var pageIds = fragmentList.map { fragmentList.hashCode().toLong() }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = fragmentList.size

    override fun createFragment(position: Int): Fragment {
        return fragmentList[position].second
    }

//    override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long = pageIds[position] // Make sure notifyDataSetChanged() works

//    override fun containsItem(itemId: Long): Boolean = pageIds.contains(itemId)

    fun getFragmentName(position: Int) = fragmentList[position].first

    fun addFragment(fragment: Pair<String, Fragment>) {
        fragmentList.add(fragment)
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    fun removeFragment(position: Int) {
        fragmentList.removeAt(position)
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

}
```

If your structure is Parent Fragment > ViewPager2 > Child Fragments the above code will work fine.

If your structure is Activity > ViewPager2 > Fragments just change

```
class AppFragmentAdapter(private val fragmentList: MutableList<Pair<String, Fragment>>, fragment: Fragment) : FragmentStateAdapter(fragment)
```

to

```
class AppFragmentAdapter(private val fragmentList: MutableList<Pair<String, Fragment>>, fragment: FragmentActivity) : FragmentStateAdapter(fragment)
```

then instead of

```
val adapter = AppFragmentAdapter(fragmentList, this)
```

pass the Fragment's activity like this

```
val adapter = AppFragmentAdapter(fragmentList, requireActivity())
```

Internally `FragmentStateAdapter(fragment)` from our adapter already handle which FragmentManager is supposedly use.

Activity > ViewPager2 > Fragments

```
public FragmentStateAdapter(@NonNull FragmentActivity fragmentActivity) {
    this(fragmentActivity.getSupportFragmentManager(), fragmentActivity.getLifecycle());
}
```

Parent Fragment > ViewPager2 > Child Fragments

```
public FragmentStateAdapter(@NonNull Fragment fragment) {
    this(fragment.getChildFragmentManager(), fragment.getLifecycle());
}
```

I was [deceived](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66919015/10053046) first by searching in SO about dynamically add/remove Fragment with ViewPager2 before trying the simplest approach I could come up.

Comment: I ended up implementing something similar to this.