# ViewPager2 not able to dynamically add remove fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-viewpager2

Removing/Adding fragments at index results in unexpected behaviour in Viewpager2. This was not possible with `ViewPager` but expected to work with `Viewpager2`. It causes duplicate fragments and out of sync `TabLayout`. 
[Here is a demo project](https://github.com/abhishekBansal/ViewPager2Demo) which reproduces this issue. There is a toggle button which removes a fragment and reattaches it at a particular index. In this case attached fragment should be green but it's blue and there are 2 blue fragments somehow.

here is how my adapter looks

```kotlin
class ViewPager2Adapter(activity: FragmentActivity) : FragmentStateAdapter(activity) {
    val fragmentList: MutableList<FragmentName> = mutableListOf()

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return fragmentList.size
    }

    override fun createFragment(position: Int): Fragment {
        return when (fragmentList[position]) {
            FragmentName.WHITE -> WhiteFragment()
            FragmentName.RED -> RedFragment()
            FragmentName.GREEN -> GreenFragment()
            FragmentName.BLUE -> BlueFragment()
        }
    }

    fun add(fragment: FragmentName) {
        fragmentList.add(fragment)
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    fun add(index: Int, fragment: FragmentName) {
        fragmentList.add(index, fragment)
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    fun remove(index: Int) {
        fragmentList.removeAt(index)
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    fun remove(name: FragmentName) {
        fragmentList.remove(name)
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    enum class FragmentName {
        WHITE,
        RED,
        GREEN,
        BLUE
    }
}
```

I have filed a [bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/154855492) with google as well

Answer (score 12):

Turns out that you need to override these two methods if you are working with `mutable` collections in `ViewPager2`

```kotlin
override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long {
        return fragmentList[position].ordinal.toLong()
    }

    override fun containsItem(itemId: Long): Boolean {
        val fragment = FragmentName.values()[itemId.toInt()]
        return fragmentList.contains(fragment)
    }
```

Adding these two in my current adapter fixes the problem

Comment: Did you have issue with fragments not reattaching on orientation/configuration change with this change?

Comment: @ScruffyFox I don't remember testing the configuration change scenario but that shouldn't be a problem because adapter is recreated and all fragments are recreated along with it. Make sure to create new fragments in `createFragment` always.

Comment: When I remove the fragment from the ViewPager, the associated ViewModel is null (same lifecycle as the fragment) and it doesn't update properly. How do you handle this scenario?

Comment: Maybe associate the ViewModel with the parent activity instead? Also: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel#sharing

Comment: @user2066728 its the same thing. Just convert it to corresponding Java syntax.

Comment: @user2066728 and for someone who need - I found a good Java example [here](https://github.com/1136346879/ViewPage2/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/viewpager2demo/FragmentTabStateActivity.java).

Answer (score 1):

This is weird on my side overriding

```
getItemId()
containsItem()
```

will just give [undesirable behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66919015/10053046) when using 3 kinds of Fragments.

In the end all I need was a simple `FragmentStateAdapter` class like this

```
class AppFragmentAdapter(private val fragmentList: MutableList<Pair<String, Fragment>>, fragment: Fragment) : FragmentStateAdapter(fragment) {

//    private var pageIds = fragmentList.map { fragmentList.hashCode().toLong() }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = fragmentList.size

    override fun createFragment(position: Int): Fragment {
        return fragmentList[position].second
    }

//    override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long = pageIds[position] // Make sure notifyDataSetChanged() works

//    override fun containsItem(itemId: Long): Boolean = pageIds.contains(itemId)

    fun getFragmentName(position: Int) = fragmentList[position].first

    fun addFragment(fragment: Pair<String, Fragment>) {
        fragmentList.add(fragment)
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    fun removeFragment(position: Int) {
        fragmentList.removeAt(position)
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

}
```

Too bad I search for an immediate answer on how to make ViewPager2 dynamic without giving a shot first on the simplest approach I could come up. Many answer here on SO pointing out that `getItemId()` and `containsItem()` needs to be override when adding or removing Fragment(s) on ViewPager2 which gives some headache for almost 2 days. Felt betrayed.