# How to add/remove tabs in ViewPager2 at runtime? Using only one fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, tabs, android-viewpager2

In the app I'm testing this concept, the app starts with one tab and the user can click a button inside the fragment and add a new tab with the name of an item inside a pre-defined list of movie titles. Imagine the list has 100 titles, how can I re-use the same fragment for each tab created so I don't have to make 100 fragments (one for each title)?

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61406176/viewpager2-not-able-to-dynamically-add-remove-fragment) link shows how to add/remove tabs using several fragments and a sample app.

```
class DynamicViewPagerAdapter(
    fragmentActivity: FragmentActivity,
    private val titleId: Int
) : FragmentStateAdapter(fragmentActivity) {

override fun createFragment(position: Int): Fragment {
    return DynamicFragment.getInstance(titleId)
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return titles.size
}

override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long {
    
    return position.toLong()
}

override fun containsItem(itemId: Long): Boolean {
    return titles.contains(titles[itemId.toInt()])
}

fun addTab(title: String) {
    titles.add(title)
    notifyDataSetChanged()
}

fun addTab(index: Int, title: String) {
    titles.add(index, title)
    notifyDataSetChanged()
}

fun removeTab(name: String) {
    titles.remove(name)
    notifyDataSetChanged()
}

fun removeTab(index: Int) {
    titles.removeAt(index)
    notifyDataSetChanged()
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out, a very important part was to keep ordinals. In the process of removing tabs, the adapter makes multiple calls to getItemId() and containsItem(). In this process the adapter uses the position of the tab and the ordinal of the item in the tab. In the [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61406176/viewpager2-not-able-to-dynamically-add-remove-fragment) I found which uses different fragments and a predefined number of them, they use enum to get the ordinals, while I used a MutableMap (titles and keys; ordinals as values). [Here](https://github.com/edcres/test-apps/tree/master/test-viewpager2)'s the link to the finished test app.

I used these global variable (only as a test):

```
// pre-defined list of titles
val testMovieTitles = listOf(
    "Hulk", "Chucky", "Cruella", "Nobody", "Scar Face",
    "Avatar", "Joker", "Profile", "Saw", "Ladies")

val titles = mutableListOf("All Movies")
val titlesOrdinals: MutableMap<String, Int> = mutableMapOf("All Movies" to 0)

const val MY_LOG = "MY_LOG"
```

The activity:

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import com.example.testmyviewpager2.*
import com.example.testmyviewpager2.databinding.ActivityDynamicViewPagerBinding
import com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayoutMediator

class DynamicViewPagerActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

private var binding: ActivityDynamicViewPagerBinding? = null
var titleIncrementer = 0 // to use the next tile until it doesn't match one of the tabs

val activityViewPagerAdapter: DynamicViewPagerAdapter by lazy {
    DynamicViewPagerAdapter(this)}

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = ActivityDynamicViewPagerBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(binding!!.root)

    setUpTabs()
    addTabFabOnClick()
}

private fun setUpTabs() {
    binding!!.dynamicViewPager.offscreenPageLimit = 4
    binding!!.dynamicViewPager.adapter = activityViewPagerAdapter

    // Set the title of the tabs
    TabLayoutMediator(binding!!.dynamicTabLayout, binding!!.dynamicViewPager) { tab, position ->
        tab.text = titles[position]
    }.attach()
}

private fun addTabFabOnClick() {
    binding!!.addTabFab.setOnClickListener {
        val nextTitlePosition = titles.size - 1
        val nextOrdinalId = titlesOrdinals.size - 1
        var nextTitle = testMovieTitles[nextTitlePosition]

        // if a title has been added before, don't add it
        // new tabs cannot have the same name as old tabs
        while(titles.contains(nextTitle)) {
            titleIncrementer++
            nextTitle = testMovieTitles[nextTitlePosition + titleIncrementer]
        }
        if (titleIncrementer > 0) { Log.d("${MY_LOG}Activity", "incrementer: $titleIncrementer") }

        if(!titles.contains(nextTitle)) {
            activityViewPagerAdapter.addTab(nextOrdinalId+1, nextTitle)
        } else {
            Log.d("${MY_LOG}Activity", "\t\t titles contains next title \t\t $titles $nextTitle")}
    }
}
}
```

The re-usable fragment:

```
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import com.example.testmyviewpager2.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_dynamic.*

class DynamicFragment : Fragment() {

private var fragmentViewPagerAdapter: DynamicViewPagerAdapter? = null
private var titleToDisplay = "All Movies"

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dynamic, container, false)
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    // get the adapter instance from the main activity
    fragmentViewPagerAdapter = (activity as? DynamicViewPagerActivity)!!.activityViewPagerAdapter
    removeButtonOnClick()
    dynamic_fragment_text.text = titleToDisplay
    Log.d("${MY_LOG}fragCreated", "name: ${titleToDisplay}")
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
}

override fun onDestroy() {
    Log.d("${MY_LOG}destroyed", "\t\t\t $titles")
    Log.d("${MY_LOG}destroyed", "\t\t\t $titlesOrdinals")
    super.onDestroy()
}

private fun removeButtonOnClick() {
    removeButton.setOnClickListener {

        val numOfTabs = titles.size
        if (numOfTabs > 1 && titleToDisplay != "All Movies") {
            fragmentViewPagerAdapter!!.removeTab(titleToDisplay)
        }
    }
}

fun setTitleText(title: String) {
    titleToDisplay = title
}

companion object{
    //The Fragment retrieves the Item from the List and display the content of that item.
    fun getInstance(titleId: Int): DynamicFragment {
        val thisDynamicFragment = DynamicFragment()
        val titleToDisplay = titles[titleId]
        thisDynamicFragment.setTitleText(titleToDisplay)
        return thisDynamicFragment
    }
}
}
```

The ViewPager2 Adapter:

```
import android.util.Log
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity
import androidx.viewpager2.adapter.FragmentStateAdapter
import com.example.testmyviewpager2.*

class DynamicViewPagerAdapter(fragmentActivity: FragmentActivity) : FragmentStateAdapter(fragmentActivity) {

private val theActivity = DynamicViewPagerActivity()

override fun createFragment(position: Int): Fragment {
    // Used this to change the text inside each fragment
    return DynamicFragment.getInstance(titles.size-1)
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return titles.size
}

override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long {
    return titlesOrdinals[titles[position]]!!.toLong()
}

// called when a tab is removed
override fun containsItem(itemId: Long): Boolean {
    var thisTitle = "No Title"
    titlesOrdinals.forEach{ (k, v) ->
        if(v == itemId.toInt()) {
            thisTitle = k
        }
    }
    return titles.contains(thisTitle)
}

fun addTab(ordinal: Int, title: String) {
    titles.add(title)

    // don't rewrite an ordinal
    if(!titlesOrdinals.containsKey(title)) {
        titlesOrdinals[title] = ordinal
    }
    notifyDataSetChanged()
    Log.d("${MY_LOG}created", "\t\t\t $titles")
    Log.d("${MY_LOG}created", "\t\t\t $titlesOrdinals")
}

fun removeTab(name: String) {
    titles.remove(name)
    notifyDataSetChanged()
    Log.d("${MY_LOG}removeTab", "----------------")
}

fun removeTab(index: Int) {
    titles.removeAt(index)
    notifyDataSetChanged()
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve this by using one Fragment that you pass the id of the item to. The Fragment will then need to retrieve the Item from the List and display the content of that item. Here is an example pager adapter.

```
private inner class SamplePagerAdapter(activity: AppCompatActivity, private val itemId: Int): FragmentStateAdapter(activity) {
            override fun getItemCount(): Int {
                return 100
            }
    
            override fun createFragment(position: Int): Fragment {
                return ItemFragment.newInstance(itemId)
            }
        }
```

Comment: It looks like this would help me choosing what to display inside the fragments corresponding to their tabs. My main problem is adding the tabs using the same fragment, so probably overriding 'getItemId()' and 'containsItem()'. I will update my post with my current adapter and here's the  adapter that uses several fragments (notice the enum class): https://github.com/abhishekBansal/ViewPager2Demo/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/abhishek/viewpager2demo/ViewPager2Adapter.kt

Comment: Update: I ended up using a global variable instead of the 'itemId' parameter because I was stuck and this is only a test app. In my real app I'm populating a recyclerview with data from a SQLite repository.